# Python Pandas Groupby not working as expected

Tags: python, pandas

I have a single dataframe like the following:

```
               ip              domain
0  46.101.214.145  cnwkabrnyld1c0[.]com
1  46.101.214.145        anfj63m[.]com
2  46.101.214.145       anf3xnem[.]com
3   69.195.129.70  cnwkabrnyld1c0[.]com
4   69.195.129.70        anfj63ms[.]com
```

I am trying to groupby the "ip" column such that it will aggregate the duplicates onto the same line.

Desired output:

```
               ip              domain
0  46.101.214.145  cnwkabrnyld1c0[.]com | anfj63m[.]com | anf3xnem[.]com
3   69.195.129.70  cnwkabrnyld1c0[.]com
4   69.195.129.70        anfj63ms[.]com
```

This seems pretty straight forward based on the countless SOF and Panda documentation I've been reading.

Here's my code:

```
pDNSPanda = pd.read_csv('/tmp/pDNSCSV.csv', names=['ip', 'domain'])
g = pDNSPanda.groupby("ip").agg('|'.join)
```

Here's what I actually get:

```
                 domain
ip
0.0.0.0       ip|domain
1.1.1.200     ip|domain
1.148.56.163  ip|domain
1.167.81.129  ip|domain
1.193.28.230  ip|domain
```

Edit:

It was suggested that I try my own code against the above data set.

```
test.csv
46.101.214.145  cnwkabrnyld1c0[.]com
46.101.214.145        anfj63m[.]com
46.101.214.145       anf3xnem[.]com
69.195.129.70  cnwkabrnyld1c0[.]com
69.195.129.70        anfj63ms[.]com

>>> import pandas as pd
>>> p = pd.read_csv('/tmp/test.csv', names=['ip', 'domain'])
>>> g = p.groupby("ip").agg("|".join)
>>> print g
                                         domain
ip
46.101.214.145        anfj63m[.]com   ip|domain
46.101.214.145       anf3xnem[.]com   ip|domain
46.101.214.145  cnwkabrnyld1c0[.]com  ip|domain
69.195.129.70        anfj63ms[.]comp|domain
69.195.129.70  cnwkabrnyld1c0[.]com   ip|domain
```

Comment: Interesting - I get the desired result with your code. Are you sure your initial DataFrame is the one posted?

Comment: It's actually a lot bigger, and I sanitized the domains (for security sake) with [.] instead of .

Comment: your code seems to be correct ...

Comment: @gleb1783, try your code against your own data sample

Comment: No luck (see updated answer)

Comment: You are joining the column names of your dataframe per your code.

Comment: How do I join the columns themselves? LOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `domain` between the `groupby` and `agg` commands.  Add spacing around you pipe join if desired, e.g. `' | '.join(...)`.

```
pDNSPanda.groupby("ip").domain.agg('|'.join)

ip
46.101.214.145    cnwkabrnyld1c0[.]com|anfj63m[.]com|anf3xnem[.]com
69.195.129.70                   cnwkabrnyld1c0[.]com|anfj63ms[.]com
Name: domain, dtype: object
```

If you have floats in your domains, it is best to convert them to strings.

```
df['domain'] = df.domain.astype(str)
```

Comment: When I do this I get a TypeError: TypeError: sequence item 24: expected string, float found

Comment: means an item in the domain is a float.

Comment: So I just looped through my entire subset of data and printed the Python type for every item (both IP and Domain). No floats...

Comment: Try a smaller subset of data, eg.g `head()` and see if it works with that.  If so, keep chunking until you find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think this first values in column `ip` are unique like my first and second row - then you get only one value in column `domain` after `groupby`:

```
print pDNSPanda
               ip                domain
0         0.0.0.0             ip|domain
1       1.1.1.200             ip|domain
2  46.101.214.145  cnwkabrnyld1c0[.]com
3  46.101.214.145         anfj63m[.]com
4  46.101.214.145        anf3xnem[.]com
5   69.195.129.70  cnwkabrnyld1c0[.]com
6   69.195.129.70        anfj63ms[.]com


g = pDNSPanda.groupby("ip").agg('|'.join)
print g
                                                           domain
ip                                                               
0.0.0.0                                                 ip|domain
1.1.1.200                                               ip|domain
46.101.214.145  cnwkabrnyld1c0[.]com|anfj63m[.]com|anf3xnem[.]com
69.195.129.70                 cnwkabrnyld1c0[.]com|anfj63ms[.]com
```

But I think is better use `groupby` with aggregate column, as `Alexander` mentioned in his answer.